# c++ 2D vector for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a text file with data and I have put that into a 2D vector. I can print all of the data with this loop.

```
int M = 1024; int N = 768   // row / column
int R = 49; int C = 36      // row / column

for (double bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R)
    for (double by = 0; by < N; by += C)
    {
        for (int x = 0; ((x < R) && ((bx + x) < M)); ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; ((y < C) && ((by + y) < N)); ++y)
            {
                if ((bx + x) >= M) 
                {
                    std::cout << (bx + x) << (by + y) << " ";

                }
                cout << MainIMG_2DVector[bx + x][by + y] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
    }
```

If I want to get the first block of the data, I use this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
        {
            cout << MainIMG_2DVector[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
```

When I compare the First block with the Data from the text file, it is correct.

However if I get the Second Block of data and compare it with the text file, it is incorrect.

```
for (int i = 49; i < 98; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 36; j < 72; j++)
        {
            cout << MainIMG_2DVector[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
```

I know the second loop is wrong but I don't know how to fix this.
Can someone please help me.

Comment: Please post the full code. I do not have even an idea how you declared your arrays. Also M,N,R and C are const, right? And why are you using doubles?

Comment: Where is your second block of data with respect to first block? You changed to both row and column for second block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear at all what you want, but when i've wrote this i imagined the table, and your code gives the "II quadrant" and the "IV quadrant", like in a plane geometry.
Maybe, for getting "III quadrant" it is:

```
    for (int i = 49; i < 98; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
     {
          cout << MainIMG_2DVector[i][j] << " ";
     }
  }
```